# How to check whether a string contains a substring in Mule?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule-el

I want to use the Assert Equals component to find if a string exists in my payload. I give an example:

Txt|Name=ST CLAUD|Country=SPAIN|Txtld=45

I want to search if the payload contains the string "SPAIN" Is there a mule expression MEL to do that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use Assert True instead of Assert Equals and use the `contains` method defined in `java.lang.Stirng` (assumed payload is of type String!).

**example**:

```
<munit:test name="dataweaveTest" description="MUnit Test">
    <munit:set payload="Txt|Name=ST CLAUD|Country=SPAIN|Txtld=45" doc:name="Set Message"/>
    <munit:assert-true doc:name="Assert True"
        condition="#[payload.contains('SPAINA')]" />
</munit:test>
```

**here is what it looks like in AnypointStudio**:
[image]